# Git alias - multiple shell commands fails on last command

Tags: git, macos, shell

I have this git alias:

```
[alias]
# rebase feature branch onto current branch (typically release branch)
rebm = !sh -c 'echo rebasing branch \"$0\" on top of \"$1\" && git checkout \"$0\" && git pull origin \"$0\" && git rebase \"$1\" && git checkout \"$1\" && git merge \"$0\" && echo all done && exit 1'
```

And last commands everytime fails, if is it anything - for example: git status, exit 1, etc. Everytime i get "xyz: command not found" for last command.

I am running it on OSX.
Console output is:

```
git rebm featbranch releasebranch
... standard git output ...
featbranch:  exit: command not found
fatal: While expanding alias 'rebm': 'sh -c 'echo rebasing branch "$0" on top of "$1" && git checkout "$0" && git pull origin "$0" && git rebase "$1" && git checkout "$1" && git merge "$0" && echo all done && exit 1'': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Add `-x` to the alias and see what commands git is actually running?

Comment: Regardless of the issue here, have you considered, for better readability, writing a script rather than put all those commands inline in the definition of your alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adam sent me this .gitconfig file, so I was able to find out the reason - it was caused by non-printable character in his alias:

```
$ cat -v -e -t .gitconfig
rebm = !sh -c 'echo rebasing branch \"$0\" on top of \"$1\" && git checkout \"$0\" && git pull origin \"$0\" && git rebase \"$1\" && git checkout \"$1\" && git merge \"$0\" && echo all done &&M-BM- exit 1'$
```

so you can now clearly see the problem at the end of the line: `&&M-BM- exit 1`

More about this kind of characters:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters